# how to pass variable argument to context.execute_steps in python-behave

Tags: python-behave

I want to execute certain step before executing my function. The step takes variable as an argument. I am not able to pass it in context.execute_steps.

```
eg.
call1 = "version"
call1_method = "get"

context.execute_steps('''When execute api{"method":call1_method, "call":call1}''')
```

however this does not work. I get error in argument parsing because variables are not in quotes. I don't see any such example in behave documentation. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

There's a bunch of stuff that could be going on. I found [here](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/126) that if you're using python 3 you need to make it unicode by including a `u` in front of `'''`. I also was a bit tripped up that you have to include when, then or given as part of execute step command (not just the name of the step), but your example seems to be doing that. I'm kind of confused by what the way you're passing variables but can tell you this how you use execute_steps and works in python 2 & 3 with behave 1.2.5.

```
@step('I set the Number to "{number:d}" exactly')
def step_impl(context, number):
    context.number = 10
    context.number = number

@step('I call another step')
def step_impl(context):
    context.execute_steps(u'''when I set the Number to "5" exactly''')
    print(context.number)
    assert context.number == 10, 'This will fail'
```

Then calling:

```
Given I call another step
When some not mentioned step
Then some other not mentioned step
```

Would execute when `I set the Number to "5" exactly` as part of the when `I call another step`.

Hard to say for your exact example because I'm unfamiliar with the other step you're trying to execute but if you defined the previous step with something like:

```
@step('execute api "{method}" "{version}"')
def step_impl(context, method, version):
    # do stuff with passed in method and version variables
```

you should the be able to use it like so in another step.

```
@step('I call another step')
def step_impl(context):
    context.execute_steps(u'''When execute api "get" "version1"''')
```

If your problem is just passing information between steps. You could just use context to pass it between them.

```
@step('I do the first function')
def step_impl(context):
   context.call1 = "version"
   context.call1_method = "get"

@step('I call another step')
def step_impl(context):
    print(%s and %s are available in this function % (context.call1, context.call1_method)
```

And then call the steps in a row

```
When I do the first function
  And I call another step
  ...
```

Comment: `@step('I call another step')
def step_impl(context):
    context.execute_steps(u'''When execute api "get" "version1"''')`

This is what I wanted. I was struggling to get this syntax. I will try and update if it works. Thanks a ton for your efforts in explaining.

Comment: Glad to help.  Let me know if that wasn't it.